# tag navbar does not work in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm still new in javascript especially in reactjs. I have a problem when creating a web header. I want to put the menu on the right and I use . But it does not work, the menu stays on the left. I am using bulma for css. Can anyone help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Header.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav has-shadow">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="nav-left">
          <a className="nav-item">MyCompany</a>
        </div>

        <span className="nav-toggle" >
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </span>

        <div className="nav-right nav-menu">

          <Link to="/" className="nav-item r-item">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/faq" className="nav-item r-item">Features</Link>
          <Link to="/faq" className="nav-item r-item">About</Link>
          <Link to="/faq" className="nav-item r-item">faq</Link>



          <div className="nav-item">
            <p className="control">
              <a className="button is-primary is-outlined">
                <span className="icon">
                  <i className="fa fa-download"></i>
                </span>
                <span>Join Now</span>
              </a>
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `navbar-end` class to place your menu contents right side like

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-end">
       <div class="navbar-item">
          <!-- Your content here -->
       </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

For documentation about header/navbar in Bulma CSS refer [Navbar | Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/)

Comment: Thanks! simply use <navbar-end> to put the menu on the right side and it works.